# get the index of the ClistBox item on Mouse over

Tags: c++, mfc, clistbox

I have a simple CListBox control. I dynamically add texts in it. Is it possible to get the index of the item over which the mouse is currently hovering on the listbox?
Basically, I want to display a tool tip for each item in the listBox based on the mouse position.

Code samples are really appreciated.

Comment: I basically want to do exactly what is done [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/457444/listbox-control-with-tooltip-for-each-item) but in MFC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CListBox::ItemFromPoint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9.aspx#clistbox__itemfrompoint) member returns the item index of the item nearest to a point.

The point needs to be in client coordinates of the `CListBox`. If you receive them in screen coordinates (e.g. by calling [GetCursorPos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390.aspx)), you will have to translate them calling [CWnd::ScreenToClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/49a832ee-bc34-4126-88b3-bc1d9974f6c4.aspx#cwnd__screentoclient) on the `CListBox`.

The second parameter (*bOutside*) tells you, whether the position is over an item or not. The member function returns `FALSE` or `TRUE`, respectively.

Comment: @lifeOfPi: What sort of code do you have in mind? There is really nothing more than calling a simple member function. If you need help with that, you shouldn't be using MFC to being with.

Comment: I am trying to handle the MouseHover event using OnMouseHover(..); but that too doesn't seem to get called. Its just a dialog with the listbox on it. So, I was requesting for some code samples.

Comment: @lifeOfPi: If you have problems with receiving or handling mouse hover messages, then go ahead an [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). This is unrelated to the question you asked here, and I fully answered that question.

Comment: Okey... I get the mouse pointer on the dilaog, but not on the ListBox. How do i get the mouse position on the listbox?

Comment: @lifeOfPi: Again, that's a different question. If you have difficulty getting the mouse position in your listbox, then ask that question. But really, those problems are so basic, that if you have any difficulty at all, you should not be using MFC. Or C++ for that matter. Or any framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer so that others can get help in case some one else is facing this problem.
First things first; you can't directly handle mouse move messages from Clistbox. So, you create a new class based on ClistBox class and then handle OnMouseMove() in that class.Then, inside that OnMouseMove() function you should get the item in the clistbox based on the mouse coordinates (as mentioned by  IInspectable).

For code example; see below.

```
BOOL b;
int n = ItemFromPoint(point,b);
CString str;
GetText( n,str);
AfxMessageBox(str);
```